# Issues printing a character string in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm new to MATLAB and I'm having problems printing a character array to a file.  I only get the first character printed out.  I read lines from a file and build an matrix of matrices.  One matrix is an array of character vectors.  Here's how I read the data

```
tline = fgetl(iin);
t_current = tline(9:34);
...       
data.t      = [data.t; t_current];
```

Then later I do this:

```
npts = length(data.t);
fid1 = fopen(fname, 'w');
fprintf(fid1, 'Day            Rank\n');
fprintf(fid1, '-------        -------\n');
for k = 1:npts
    time_str = data.t(k);
    fprintf(fid1, '%s     %f3\n',time_str, data.rank(k));
end
```

fclose(fid1);

data.t is <10082,26 char> and looks something like this:

```
val =
2015-07-16T03:28:36.410305
2015-07-16T03:29:00.000000
...
```

All I get with the fprintf is a '2'.  I tried to use convertCharsToStrings but that failed with an error message: Undefined function 'convertCharsToStrings' for input arguments of type
'char'.

This must be something simple I'm missing.
Thanks,
-Mike

Comment: Is the 3 after `%f` necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Since "data.t is <10082,26 char>", try this:

```matlab
...
for k = 1:npts
    time_str = data.t(k, :);
...
```

If you do not use the `, :`, Matlab will use linear indexing for the matrix as opposed to subscripts.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to use a different format for getting the time string:

```
time_str=data.t(k,1:end)
```

Comment: Instead of posting a repeat answer, please upvote and accept the answer that pointed out your issue.

Comment: In fact, I see you have many questions, and haven't accepted a single answer. Please read [this page in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).